# Sum a column with conditional from another table (power bi)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I'm having trouble finding a solution to my problem.

I need to add up the billing amount from all the bills. however, I need to discount the canceled invoices, which are kept in the database as a record. we use two tables to control invoices: **invoices (header)** and **invoicesitems (items)**.

where, the quantity is in the items table, and my conditional (which determines if the note is voided or not), is in the header table.

when creating a measure to perform this sum, I tried to do it as follows:

`voided_amt = calculate(sum(invoicesitems[amount]), invoices[voided]=1)`

where, invoice[void] = 1, it means that the invoice is canceled.

but it ends up not working, and the measurement is blank.

how can I make this sum, with this filter/conditional from another table, in power bi?

NOTE: the relationship between the **invoices** and **invoicesitems** tables is the id_nf column (1xN)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Model view i.e. Power Pivot and create relationship 1XN between
invoices and invoicesitems. Then Measure works fine.

As an example see the attached image
[image]